# Interrupted time series in R: combining datasets with different lengths, start and end dates, and interruptions

Tags: r, time-series

I am conducting an interrupted time series analysis in R. I am examining the effectiveness of an intervention on an outcome variable. The intervention has been tested in 10 different organisations. My initial plan was to examine the effectiveness of the intervention for each of the organisations separately.

However, I would prefer to combine the datasets of the 10 organisations and conduct the interrupted time series on the merged data, to see the effect of the intervention on all organisations. But I have ran into a problem: the 10 organisations all have different baseline lengths, have implemented the intervention on different dates, and differ in the length of the intervention.

Does anyone have experience with aligning time series data for the purpose of interrupted time series analysis?
I actually do not think this is possible in this case, because the lengths of the interventions differ between organisations, and manipulating the data (e.g. shortening the lengths of interventions or baselines) would lead to bias in the data.

The data look like this:

```
# Dataset 1
time <- c("1", "2", "3", "4",
           "5", "6", "7", "8")
week <- c("32", "33", "34", "35",
          "36", "37", "38", "39")
year <- c("2020", "2020", "2020", "2020",
            "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020")
outcome <- c(56, 76, 86, 96, 73, 87, 47, 98)
intervention <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

organisation1_df <- data.frame(time, week, year, outcome, intervention)

# Dataset 2
time <- c("1", "2", "3", "4",
           "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
           "11", "12")
week <- c("12", "13", "14", "15",
          "16", "17", "18", "19",
          "20", "21", "22", "23")
year <- c("2020", "2020", "2020", "2020",
           "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020",
           "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020")
outcome <- c(33, 44, 45, 34, 45, 34, 33, 32,
              32, 32, 33, 43)
intervention <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

organisation2_df <- data.frame(time, week, year, outcome, intervention)
```

```
> organisation1_df
  time week year outcome intervention
1    1   32 2020      56            0
2    2   33 2020      76            0
3    3   34 2020      86            0
4    4   35 2020      96            1
5    5   36 2020      73            1
6    6   37 2020      87            1
7    7   38 2020      47            1
8    8   39 2020      98            1

> organisation2_df
   time week year outcome intervention
1     1   12 2020      33            0
2     2   13 2020      44            0
3     3   14 2020      45            0
4     4   15 2020      34            0
5     5   16 2020      45            0
6     6   17 2020      34            0
7     7   18 2020      33            0
8     8   19 2020      32            1
9     9   20 2020      32            1
10   10   21 2020      32            1
11   11   22 2020      33            1
12   12   23 2020      43            1
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

I have converted data from both dataframes into time series and merged those using "merge", but of course ran into the problem that the "intervention" columns are different.

```
merged <- merge(organisation1, organisation2, by="time", all = T)
```

Comment: I think I started answering too early; what exactly is the result supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some tidyverse code to construct the data frame.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(nlme)
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)

# Combine data
df <- bind_rows(
    organisation1_df |> mutate(organisation = "1"),
    organisation2_df |> mutate(organisation = "2")
  ) |>
  mutate(
    week = yearweek(paste(year, week, sep = " W")),
    time = as.numeric(week),
    time = time - min(time) + 1
  ) |>
  select(-year)
```

```r
df
#>    time     week outcome intervention organisation
#> 1    21 2020 W32      56            0            1
#> 2    22 2020 W33      76            0            1
#> 3    23 2020 W34      86            0            1
#> 4    24 2020 W35      96            1            1
#> 5    25 2020 W36      73            1            1
#> 6    26 2020 W37      87            1            1
#> 7    27 2020 W38      47            1            1
#> 8    28 2020 W39      98            1            1
#> 9     1 2020 W12      33            0            2
#> 10    2 2020 W13      44            0            2
#> 11    3 2020 W14      45            0            2
#> 12    4 2020 W15      34            0            2
#> 13    5 2020 W16      45            0            2
#> 14    6 2020 W17      34            0            2
#> 15    7 2020 W18      33            0            2
#> 16    8 2020 W19      32            1            2
#> 17    9 2020 W20      32            1            2
#> 18   10 2020 W21      32            1            2
#> 19   11 2020 W22      33            1            2
#> 20   12 2020 W23      43            1            2
```

You haven't said how you want to evaluate the intervention, but here are several possibilities

```r
# Estimate intervention for each organisation separately
# allowing for any possible autocorrelation using ARIMA
df |>
  as_tsibble(index = week, key = organisation) |>
  model(ARIMA(outcome ~ intervention)) |>
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   organisation .model                term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>        <chr>                 <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 1            ARIMA(outcome ~ inte… inte…     7.53     12.2      0.617 5.54e- 1
#> 2 1            ARIMA(outcome ~ inte… inte…    72.7       9.65     7.53  6.72e- 5
#> 3 2            ARIMA(outcome ~ inte… inte…    -3.89      2.97    -1.31  2.15e- 1
#> 4 2            ARIMA(outcome ~ inte… inte…    38.3       1.92    20.0   1.42e-10
```

```r
# Estimate intervention jointly for all organisations
# ignoring autocorrelation, treating organisation as fixed effect
lm(outcome ~ intervention + organisation, data = df) |>
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   term          estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)     77.0        5.72    13.5   1.69e-10
#> 2 intervention     0.583      5.75     0.101 9.20e- 1
#> 3 organisation2  -40.6        5.87    -6.92  2.48e- 6
```

```r
# Estimate intervention jointly for all organisations
# ignoring autocorrelation, treating organisation as random effect
lme(outcome ~ intervention, random = ~ 1 | organisation, data = df) |>
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   effect   group        term          estimate std.error    df statistic p.value
#>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 fixed    <NA>         (Intercept)     56.5       20.5     17     2.76   0.0134
#> 2 fixed    <NA>         intervention     0.752      5.75    17     0.131  0.897 
#> 3 ran_pars organisation sd_(Intercep…   28.4       NA       NA    NA     NA     
#> 4 ran_pars Residual     sd_Observati…   12.6       NA       NA    NA     NA
```

```r
# Estimate intervention jointly for all organisations
# allowing for autocorrelation using AR(1), treating organisation as random effect
nlme::lme(outcome ~ intervention, random = ~ 1 | organisation,
          corr = nlme::corAR1(form = ~ time | organisation),
          data = df) |>
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   effect   group        term          estimate std.error    df statistic p.value
#>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 fixed    <NA>         (Intercept)     57.5       20.6     17     2.79   0.0127
#> 2 fixed    <NA>         intervention    -0.987      4.46    17    -0.221  0.827 
#> 3 ran_pars organisation sd_(Intercep…   28.8       NA       NA    NA     NA     
#> 4 ran_pars Residual     sd_Observati…   12.3       NA       NA    NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking to convert the data from individual organisations into time series and then merging them somehow. I briefly considered the option to use multilevel analysis. Seeing the options you're providing here makes a lot of sense - multilevel modelling with autocorrelation seems the most fitting for my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First you might want to put your data frames in a `list`. Then add id column using `Map`, `rbind` it and `order` presumably by `c('year', 'week', 'time')`.

```
> org_lst <- list(org1=organisation1_df, org2=organisation2_df)
> Map(`[<-`, org_lst, 'id', value=names(org_lst)) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> 
+   {\(.) .[do.call('order', .[c('year', 'week', 'time')]), ]}()
        time week year outcome intervention   id
org2.1     1   12 2020      33            0 org2
org2.2     2   13 2020      44            0 org2
org2.3     3   14 2020      45            0 org2
org2.4     4   15 2020      34            0 org2
org2.5     5   16 2020      45            0 org2
org2.6     6   17 2020      34            0 org2
org2.7     7   18 2020      33            0 org2
org2.8     8   19 2020      32            1 org2
org2.9     9   20 2020      32            1 org2
org2.10   10   21 2020      32            1 org2
org2.11   11   22 2020      33            1 org2
org2.12   12   23 2020      43            1 org2
org1.1     1   32 2020      56            0 org1
org1.2     2   33 2020      76            0 org1
org1.3     3   34 2020      86            0 org1
org1.4     4   35 2020      96            1 org1
org1.5     5   36 2020      73            1 org1
org1.6     6   37 2020      87            1 org1
org1.7     7   38 2020      47            1 org1
org1.8     8   39 2020      98            1 org1
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered putting the data in a list. But this was what I was looking for. The tidyverse code provided by Rob Hyndman seems more efficient to me so I have accepted this as the answer.